# How can I integrate angular2-google-maps in a VS2015 project?

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, npm, angular

I have just made an ASP.NET 5 web application using angular 2 following this tutorial:

http://bifrost.pro/page/asp-net-5-and-angular-2/

Now I want to add angular2-google-maps. I know that I can install it through npm with the following command:

npm install --save angular2-google-maps

but from which folder of my project should I launch this command? From wwwroot or from the upper folder?

Answer (score 0):

In reality you don't have to use npm directly. You just need to update your package.json file by adding the following line in the dependencies:

"angular2-google-map": "^0.1.8"

and save the file. But after this I don't know how to proceed.